# How to break on handle exception C# on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I want to VSCode stop on exception at the line `throw new Exception`, but seem add "*Exception*" at **Breakpoints** section not working. How to fix this?

[image]

The sample code: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnLYgH4sUs2EpPMoeF3swRWjc8z3vA?e=t4ygt5

Comment: Are you running application in Debug Mode or release mode? Make Sure its debug mode

Comment: Of course it's debug mode, it check "All Exceptions" and it worked

Answer (score -1):

[Check your tests.JSON file in .vscode folder and check Terminal setting in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U833M.png)

Comment: What is the image link about? does it help in the answer at all?

Comment: I want to VSCode stop on exception at the line `throw new Exception`. Please look at BREAKPOINTS section. I don't have problem with set a breakpoint by click the line